# SD card reader (Realtek 522a) not working in Dell i7559 in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: drivers, 15.10, realtek, sd-card

My new Dell Inspiron i7559 is not recognizing any SD cards. I had installed Ubuntu Mate 15.10, and everything else (including wifi) worked fine. However, at the start, the SD card reader device was not working. The output of `lspci -nnk` was as follows:

```
06:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:522a] (rev 01) 
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:522a]
```

---

FIXED: I installed the latest stable kernel 4.4.1 using deb packages, and now the SD Card Reader is working, and `lspci -nnk` returns the following:

```
06:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:522a] (rev 01) 
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:522a]
Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
```

I hope this helps someone with this new model Dell machine!

Comment: @DavidFoerster, the above command simply returns a blank line.  

amrita@amrita-home:~$  lspci -nnk | grep -A1 'Device 522a'  
amrita@amrita-home:~$

Comment: `amrita@amrita-home:~$  lspci -nnk | grep -A1 'Device 522a'
amrita@amrita-home:~$ `  

Apologies for not using appropriate formatting in my question and comment above.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, edited to include the output. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1. Find your current kernel version and follow the steps of any answer to [What's a simple way to recompile the kernel?](/q/163298/175814). Let's go with [the accepted answer](/a/163348/175814) for the sake of simplicity.
2. Apply the patch [mentioned in the bug report](//lkml.org/lkml/2015/10/13/133). Inside the root directory of the kernel source:

   ```
   wget -O rts522a-20150628.patch http://lkml.org/lkml/diff/2015/6/28/134/1
   patch -p1 < rts522a-20150628.patch
   ```
3. Rebuild and install the kernel starting with the command `make-kpgk` (or `make` or other steps depending on the chosen build recipe).
4. Reboot and cross your fingers.

Comment: I went with method 1 as `apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)`    

Then I input the wget command above; it downloaded the patch but returned:  

 `amrita@amrita-home:~$ patch < rts522a-20150628.patch
    can't find file to patch at input line 5
    Perhaps you should have used the -p or --strip option?
    The text leading up to this was:
    --------------------------
    |diff --git a/drivers/mfd/Kconfig b/drivers/mfd/Kconfig
    |index 6538159..614c146 100644
    |--- a/drivers/mfd/Kconfig
    |+++ b/drivers/mfd/Kconfig
    --------------------------
    File to patch:`

Comment: while trying to rebuild the kernel, I realized that I should first install the latest one. Should have done that before posting. Thank you!

Comment: I altered it to `patch -p1`. I thought, that would be the default, but oh well… Can you please try again?

Answer (score 0):

I installed [the newest stable kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.1-wily/) (v4.4.1 wily) for 15.10. This fixed the issue, and my Realtek SD card reader is working fine.